# Package acmart cannot be imported. acmart.sty not found

Tags: acmart

I am a beginner in LaTeX and excuse me if my question is basic. I have downloaded the template of `ACM Siggconf`. The  template is using `\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}`.

I have seen the text below on the ACM website.

> ```
> Please note that the following packages are included in the "acmart" package:
> amsmath
> array
> booktabs
> caption
> fancyvrb
> graphicx
> hypdoc
> libertine
> longtable
> newtxmath
> tabularx
> zi4
> ```

There is no `\usepackage` in the template. My question is that when I use `\usepackage{acmart}` I get the error below:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `acmart.sty' not found.Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,or enter new name. (Default extension: sty) Enter file name:! Emergency stop.<read > \usepackage
```

I need to use the two packages of tabular and booktabs. when I add them separately like `\usepackage{booktabs}` and `\usedpackage{tabularx}` I do not get any error. but Why I get error when I use `acmart` package? How to solve it?
when the document class is `acmart`, shouldn't it include the package `acmart` automatically? Then why I need to again add `\usepackage{acmart}`?

Comment: `amsart` is a class not a package, therefore you cannot load it with `\usepackage{acmart}`.

Comment: @DG' --  think you meant `acmart`, not `amsart`.  But otherwise, it's correct.  When one is using a `\documentclass` with a particular name, it is (almost?) unknown to have a package of the same name.

Comment: @barbarabeeton oops, that was a typo